# How To Remove object from Javascript Object Array By Value?

Tags: javascript

I am having array of objects defined in javascript and would like to delete values based on object property.

I used below code :

```
     var addedItems = [];
     var item = {};
     item["TId"] = "";
     item["VNo"] = "";
     item["IDate"] = "";
     item["Rate"] = 22;
     item["ItemId"] = 12;
     item["Quantity"] = 1;
     item["ItemTypeId"] = 3;
     addedItems.push(item);

     removeValueFromObjectByValue(addedItems,12);


     function removeValueFromObjectByValue(jsonObject, value) {
        jQuery.each(jsonObject, function (i, val) {
            if (val.ItemId == value) // delete index
            {
                return;
                delete jsonObject[i];
                return;
            }
        });
    }
```

Expected Result :
When I remove value, it should give me array with 0 elements.

Actual output :
When I remove value, I am getting array with 1 element and the element value is null.

Comment: Replace delete with splice, as provided in the duplicate answer. Delete doesn't accept an index as parameter, only values

Comment: Oh yes thanks, I tried and it works. Thanks a lot. Its strange that delete is not working fine.

Comment: Delete is working fine :) You can probably also change your code to delete jsonObject[value] and it will work as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` and `splice`. Inside the function create a new copy of the original array using JSON.parse & JSON.stringify so that original array does not get modified. Inside the `forEach` callback use `Object.values` which will give an array of values. Then use `includes` to check if this array created using `Object.values` contains the parameter passed in the function. If true then remove the element from the copied array using splice

```js
var addedItems = [];
var item = {};
item["TId"] = "";
item["VNo"] = "";
item["IDate"] = "";
item["Rate"] = 22;
item["ItemId"] = 12;
item["Quantity"] = 1;
item["ItemTypeId"] = 3;
addedItems.push(item);

function removeValueFromObjectByValue(arr, num) {
  let newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))
  arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
    let isNumPresent = Object.values(item).includes(num)
    if (isNumPresent) {
      newArr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  })
  return newArr;
}
console.log(removeValueFromObjectByValue(addedItems, 12));
```